# Django smart fiter transfers

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have a model Book and there are duplicated rows in that table.
One of the duplicates was changed during duplicate operation.

The differences between that rows are in two fields (special_id and state). E.g.:

| Name | special_id | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Idiot | "0107" | 1 |
| Idiot | "0106" | 2 |

During filtering by state if i write `Book.objects.filter(state=2)`, i'll get the books with value of state `2`, So i want to exclude this book if there is the book with the same name and with the state `1`

Is there any way to do this without for loop and looking by the name of every book in `QuerySet`?

Now when quantity of books is not big the delay of `for loop` is not noticeable. But when they'll be enormous i think it's going to be really long delay.

Answer (score 0):

I used `django.db.models.Q` and operations such as `|`, `&`, `~` for dynamic querying in that situation.

Comment: `Q` objects only check the same row. You probably can't go with joins easily unless you use raw queries. If you wish to use the ORM you probably would need to go with subqueries (most likely a not exists subquery).